# Dropdown List not setting selectedValue in its databind event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox, telerik

I've currently run into an error with binding causing an error when the value pulled from the database is blank.

In an attempt to fix it I am instead binding the value from the database to a label, and then looping through the items in the combobox's databound event, matching the against the label. If it finds a match, it is supposed to set the selected value of the combobox to the text value of the label (lblSalesManagerValue).

```
 <td align="left">
  <asp:Label ID="lblSalesManager" runat="server" Text="Sales Manager:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
  <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cboSalesManager" runat="server" DataSourceID="SalesManagersDataSource" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="No." Width="149px" OnDataBound="cboSalesManager_DataBound" />
  <asp:Label ID="lblSalesManagerValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SM") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server"
  ErrorMessage="Please select Sales Manager." Text="&nbsp;*" ControlToValidate= "cboSalesManager"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 </td>
```

I am working in VB, using a Telerik RadGrid.

```
Protected Sub cboSalesManager_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim cbo As RadComboBox = DirectCast(sender, RadComboBox)
    Dim gr As GridEditFormItem = DirectCast(cbo.Parent.NamingContainer, GridEditFormItem)

    For Each itm As RadComboBoxItem In cbo.Items
        If itm.Value.ToString = CType(gr.FindControl("lblSalesManagerValue"), Label).Text Then

            cbo.SelectedValue = CType(gr.FindControl("lblSalesManagerValue"), Label).Text

            CType(gr.FindControl("lblTest"), Label).Text = CType(gr.FindControl("lblTest"), Label).Text & ";" & cbo.SelectedValue.ToString
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Everything fires, as I get a semicolon beside my combobox, but the value just won't set for some reason and I am baffled.

Edit: After playing with it some more, I have discovered that nothing from that label will stick. I tried setting the test label (I'd response.write but this is an asynchronous call) and it won't set either.

Comment: The from you label exists in the dropdownlist?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? The label with the database value is next to the drop down list, same GridItem, same table row and column. Just beside it.

Comment: You dont know how to debug the code?

Comment: By the way your code shows you are binding nothing with the lblText.

Comment: I'm trying to set the combobox with the text value of the "lblSalesManagerValue" Label, the test label is for my debug purposes, as Response.write won't work in an asynchronous call.

Comment: drop your pages here. http://pastelink.me/ .. i will check the code to see if i can help you out.

Comment: http://pastelink.me/dl/7c3027

Thanks so much! I'll keep poking to see what's going on as well.

Comment: send aspx page as well.

Comment: oops! my bad. http://pastelink.me/dl/1990a4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The combobox was binding before the label. I added a forced

```
CType(gr.FindControl("lblSalesManagerValue"), Label).DataBind()
```

And it works perfectly. =)